# Is it possible to create a primary index for N1QL via REST API?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm using Couchbase Server 4.6.4 and I'd like to create a primary index for N1QL via REST API to automate my provision. Is it possible? I got it via web console.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the query service REST API (which is on port 8093 by default. E.g.,

```
curl http://don:don_pw@10.17.1.72:8093/query/service?statement=create%20primary%20index%20on%20default
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Reference: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate the creation of indexes, you can add a class that automatically create everything during the startup:

**Java Example:** 
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/try-cb-java/blob/master/src/main/java/trycb/util/StartupPreparations.java

UPDATE: removed my comment as I thought it wasn't possible.